# Django DeleteView SuccessMessageMixin -- how to pass data to message?

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am using **SuccessMessageMixin** on a **CreateView** and **DeleteView**.

In the **CreateView**, I can send the book title to the success_message, like so:

```
    success_message = "%(title)s added successfully"
```

Which correctly flashes "Great Expectations added successfully" on the success url.

But in **DeleteView**, I can't access the title. I can send a generic message saying "book deleted", but I can't send a message saying "Great Expectations has been deleted".

Is there a way that I can pass info about what's being deleted to the **success_message**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because a `DeleteView` works with an *empty* form, so without cleaned data.

You can override `get_success_message` and work with:

```
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.views.generic import DeleteView


class MyDeleteView(SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Book

    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        return f'{self.object.title} has been deleted'
```